# como usar moment.js en handlebars

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, handlebars.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const {Schema} = mongoose

const Movimiento_Schema = new Schema({
    n_doc_vacacion: {type: String, require: true},
    fecha_ini_vacacion: {type: Date, require: true},
    fecha_fin_vacacion: {type: Date, require: true}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Movimientos', Movimiento_Schema)
```

mi pregunta es como aplicar un formato ('YYYY/MM/DD') y no como el isodate de mongodb que ademas me muestra en el dom la fecha un dia antes

```js
const moment = require('moment')

app.locals.moment = require('moment')
```

```html
<tbody>
        {{#each movimientos_vacaciones}}
        <tr class="text-nowrap">
            <th scope="row">{{@index}}</th>
            <td>{{fecha_ini_vacacion}}</td>
            <td>{{fecha_fin_vacacion}}</td>
        </tr>
{{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta haciendo clic en [edit] y agrega más información. Por ejemplo, ¿qué tipo de variable es `fecha_ini_vacacion` y `fecha_fin_vacacion`.   Es un ¿timestamp? ¿string? ¿integer?. ¿Es el valor de un objeto Date?. Puedes poner un ejemplo de esas variables. Todo eso es importante para poder ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: gracias por las recomendaciones